# What's the best way to validate users conformed to requirements of a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to validate that all Jenkins pipelines, at least in a single group/organization, have published their junit tests. Is there a way to programmatically do this? Also, would it be relegated to Jenkinsfiles or work on all pipelines?  Thanks!

I could manually check this via looking for the "Test Results" on the page that I have included the image for below. This indicates that the job has published Test Results to the JUnit plugin.

[image]

If I were to write a Jenkinsfile, it might look something like this. But it is possible to attach these to the JUnit pipeline via manual methods as well:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Compile') {
            steps { 
                // Login to Repository
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'nexus_maven_configuration', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS compile'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test') { 
            steps { 
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'nexus_maven_configuration', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS test'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
            archive 'target/*.jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, your question doesn't have enough information to answer. For example, tell us how you would manually validate if Junit tests are published from a Job? Also, it would help if you can share a sample pipeline with us.

Comment: I have added details if that helps to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script you can use to check whether you have tests attached for Jobs in a specific Subdirectory. You can either run this through a Pipeline or using the Jenkins Script Console.

```
def subFolderToCheck = "folder1" // We will only check Jobs in a specific sub directory
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
      def jobName = jobitem.getFullName()
      def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
      
      // We will check if the last successfull build has any tests attached. 
      if(jobName.contains(subFolderToCheck) && jobInfo.getLastSuccessfulBuild() != null) {
        def results = jobInfo.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getActions(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).result
        println("Job : " + jobName + " Tests " + results.size())
        
        if(results == null || results.size() <= 0) {
          print("Job " + jobName + " Does not have any tests!!!!!")
          
        }               
      }    
   }
```

Comment: Got it.  That works as a solution.  Thanks!